# SQL to see the leaves of employees per year

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm using `ACCESS` to run an `SQL` query.

I want to show the leaves of **all** employees (doctors) per year.

This is my `SQL` code:

```
SELECT doctors.Name,  
31-sum(DateDiff("d",leaves.leave_starting_date,leaves.leave_end_date)) as days
FROM doctors INNER JOIN leaves ON doctors.ID = leaves.doctor_id
GROUP BY doctors.Name, YEAR(leaves.leave_starting_date)
```

I have two issues:

1. I can't see the 31 as number of leave days if a doctors does not have a leave date yet.
2. I can't distinct the leaves per year as new column.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean here *"I can't distinct the leaves per year as new column."*. As for your first question: use a LEFT OUTER JOIN instead of an INNER JOIN.

Comment: @JNevill I can see a new line per year per employee. Instead, I need to show the year per column.

Comment: Ah! Ok, in that case keep your current query as-is (changing to LEFT OUTER JOIN to solve issue 1). What you want to do is create a CROSSTAB query on top of it to put years into the columns.

Comment: @JNevill Thanks. Is there a way to show the number "31" if days are empty?

Comment: You may be able to do `31 - nz(sum(DateDiff("d",leaves.leave_starting_date,leaves.leave_end_date)), 0)` so that it's subtracting 0 instead of null.

Comment: @JNevill Thank you! If you will find a solution the step 2, please add it as response to accept it.